# Upgrading VS2005 to VS2008

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-vista

I have a small program <350ish lines of code on 5 forms>. It works fine compiled on VS2005 but doesn't run correctly on Vista. After importing through VS2008, it initially runs correctly. However, there is one main form with four subordinate ones that set the settings and attributes of the starter form. they work correctly until they are instantiated a second time then they are displayed but act like they are completely modal. The only way to remove the form is to close the start up form. Does anyone have any solutions to this?

Comment: sounds alot like buggy code. Suggest you post the offending code snippet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem is not the answer to this question. It has to do with how transparency key is handled.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are cleaning up after you close the forms and not leaving one open, but not visible. I am not sure whether this is any different in VS2005, but I have seen applications that did not completely dispose of items on a form, leaving bits in memory. While they do not create a modal form, per se, that is the feeling one has when the form is opened. Without seeing your code, I can only guess.

Comment: Your answer led me to find that there is a difference in how vs2008 handles opacity and transparency-key. My forms were being hidden under a translucent background.